# Dynamically (re)load service provider module

Tags: java, classloader, java-platform-module-system, serviceloader

I want to load and reload a service provider in a jar which is a module. It is my understanding that this can be achieved by loading the module in a new `ModuleLayer`.

Following the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114262/4860821) and the example in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html), I have succeeded in loading the module at runtime and using the service provider.

```java
var finder = ModuleFinder.of(Path.of("/path/to/module/"));

var bootLayer = ModuleLayer.boot();
var pluginLayer = bootLayer.defineModulesWithOneLoader(
        bootLayer.configuration().resolve(finder, ModuleFinder.of(), Set.of("myapp")),
        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

ServiceLoader.load(MyService.class, pluginLayer.findLoader("myapp"))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresentOrElse(
        __ -> System.out.println("Found provider."),
        () -> System.out.println("Couldn't find provider."));
```

The only thing I am unsure about is how I should go about eventually unloading the module and reloading a new version of it. The linked answer says that the unloading happens when the `ModuleLayer` is GC'd. With some testing, I have confirmed this, though this feels very finicky. Obviously, I cannot control exactly when the layer will be garbage collected, even once it is unreachable.

What would be the best approach for allowing quick reloading of the module?

Comment: As far as I know, the only option is to remove all references to the `ModuleLayer`. You should let the garbage collector decide when to actually collect the layer and just create your new layer as needed. Are you encountering any specific problems with that approach?

Comment: The handle to the jar is not released until the layer is gc'd. This is problematic as I would like to be able to replace that jar.

Comment: @Slaw Do you have any ideas regarding releasing that file handle in a timely manner?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. The module API doesn't provide a way to "close" anything, except `ModuleReader`. If an open `ModuleReader` is the problem you likely can't do much about it as you won't have access to the instance. And just like `ClassLoader`s, you can't actively dispose of `ModuleLayer`s. You also can't force a GC run. You could be _notified_ when the layer is GC'd by registering it with a `Cleaner` (but I feel that's an unintended use of the class).

Comment: I'm quite disappointed by that. I thought perhaps we finally had safe, standard APIs for this kind of thing. Back to manually using ClassLoaders I suppose.

Comment: I had hopes for that as well when the JPMS was released, but I remember reading somewhere that hot (re)deployment was not a design goal. Maybe that will change in the future. For your case, I suppose you could put the replacement JAR somewhere else (e.g. a sibling directory), but I'm personally not a fan of that approach.